# Unity. Много скриптов или один большой?

Tags: unity3d

ситуация такая: есть скрипт, в котором я создаю текстуру на quad-е, чтобы её редактировать (изменять цвета пикселей). Чтобы применить изменения, нужно обращаться к созданной в скрипте текстуре. Есть вариант сделать поле текстуры статическим и обращаться к нему из других скриптов, но это выглядит не очень красиво. Другой же вариант - нахлобучить все скрипты в один, как дочерние классы, чтобы без каких либо ссылок обращаться к текстуре.
Как лучше?
Все скрипты на одном объекте.
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Советую тебе для упрощенной работы все разбить на отдельные скрипты, тк так ошибки будет искать намного легче